# Illustration of response variable plane in multiple linear regression with 2 regressors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am pretty new in statistics and just saw the most common depiction of simple linear regression with distributions on x given y values over scattergram.

I wonder what would be the depiction of y values in case of having 2 regressors in the multiple linear regression context. Would it be something like a terrain(regression surface) with mountains(bivariate distributions of y values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only 2 predictors, e.g. $y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2+\epsilon$, then yes it could be represented as a sort of surface, although note that you might have multiple values of $y$ for the same 'coordinates' $x_1, x_2$. In that case the regression equation, giving the predicted values would be a plane (unless you are using quadratic or higher order polynomials). A useful way to visualize the regression, one that works even for more than 2 predictors, is to plot the observed $y$ against their predicted values $\hat y = y- \epsilon = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$.

Comment: so there will be no bivariate mountains, just a surface plane ?

Comment: The equation $\hat y=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$ describes a plane, so the predicted values $\hat y $ will all lie into this plane. The observed $y$ will show random deviations from the plane, giving a more 'rugged' surface.